# Symfony2 deployement with Heroku : Dumping assets

Tags: symfony, heroku

I'm using Heroku to deploy my Symfony2 app with the default configuration but assets are not dumped.

I have added to composer.json :

```
...
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "php app/console --env=prod assetic:dump"
    ]
},
...
```

Is it the right way ?

In the Procfile, doesn't work. And with :

```
heroku run php app/console --env=prod assetic:dump
```

Also doesn't work.

Thank you,

Ref : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony2

Comment: I think you should dump your assets before deploying.  It doesn't make sense to have outdated files in the repo, so you should ensure that your assets are all prod ready before committing to the repo (deploying).  That's my opinion

Comment: For collaborative work, I have to send sources and not compiled files. When the backend developer pushes the repo, he should not dump the asset itself before sending. I think that the compilation should be automatic, but where? That is my opinion also;) Thank you for your post !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "compile": [
      "rm web/app_dev.php",
      "php app/console assetic:dump --no-debug"
    ]
  },
```

Notice "compile" section. That key name is a Heroku convention.

Symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/heroku.html says you can use a [Custom Composer Command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#writing-custom-commands)

You do not need to add --env=prod option as you should add an environment variable in Heroku.

Comment: +1 @josecelano for link to [How to create and run Custom Composer Command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#writing-custom-commands)